# Value of Program Counter after jmp loop (Assembly)

Tags: assembly

I have this question in an assignment (quoted below), which I do not understand. I have tried Googling for more information on unconditional branches, goto's, jump loops, assembly language, but came with nothing.

Any type of help would be appreciated. I am still new to computer hardware. I know the answer shouldn't be too complicated. Thanks.

> All instruction sets contain *unconditional branches* ("gotos").
>   The assembly-language syntax might be 'jmp loop', where 'loop' is the label
>   on some instruction.  When the program is running, each machine instruction
>   is stored in memory, and hence has a machine address.
>
> a) [8 marks] If the processor executes a 'jmp loop' instruction, and if the
>   instruction that is labeled 'loop' lives at memory address 1,024, what is
>   the value of PC after the 'jmp loop' instruction has completed but before
>   the next instruction in program order has been fetched?  In general, how
>   do gotos alter program order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question pretty much gives itself away. From the text, the only memory address we know to even exist is 1,024, and that is indeed the answer.

More generally, a statement like

`jmp loop`

is conceptually the same as

`mov ip, offset loop` (not valid syntax, usually)

where `ip` is the instruction (or program) counter.